# Square brackets after arguments list in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function-calls, square-bracket

### Can anyone explain the meaning behind the "[0]" after the arguments list here?

> let value = this.recurseMinimax(board, !player)**[0]**;

function:

```
 recurseMinimax(board: boolean[][], player: boolean): any {
    this.numNodes++;
    let winner = this.getWinner(board);
    if (winner != null) {
      switch (winner) {
        case 1:
          return [1, board];
        case 0:
          return [-1, board];
        case -1:
          return [0, board];
      }
    } else {
      let nextVal = null;
      let nextBoard = null;

      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          if (board[i][j] == null) {
            board[i][j] = player;
            let value = this.recurseMinimax(board, !player)[0];
            if ((player && (nextVal == null || value > nextVal)) || (!player && (nextVal == null || value < nextVal))) {
              nextBoard = board.map(function (arr) {
                return arr.slice();
              });
              nextVal = value;
            }
            board[i][j] = null;
          }
        }
      }
      return [nextVal, nextBoard];
    }
  }
```

### And the "[1]" here:

> return this.recurseMinimax(board, true)**[1]**;

function:

```
minimaxMove(board: boolean[][]): any {
    this.numNodes = 0;
    return this.recurseMinimax(board, true)[1];
  }
```

Comment: Those functions will return an array, so [0] and [1] will respectively select the first and second element from that array. If we look at the function, you see that at the end it returns `return [nextVal, nextBoard];`, so [0] wil be the nextVal sent by the fn, and [1] will be the nextBoard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Means the index of the Array (that is returning from your functions) are you accessing ... be carefully to do this without do a check maybe before, for example:

```
  minimaxMove(board: boolean[][]): any {
        this.numNodes = 0;
        return this.recurseMinimax(board, true) && this.recurseMinimax(board, true).lenght>=1 ? this.recurseMinimax(board, true)[1] : {} ;
      }
```